# 'Email address and password not found' PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issues logging on to a website I have created with PHP and MySQL. After registering, you have the option to be taken to a login page however after trying to login with the correct details, 'email address and password not found' is displayed above the login where errors are displayed.

I have tried various other forums on stack overflow related to this problem but I have had no success.

Here is the code for 3 of the pages:

login.php:

```
<?php

$page_title='Login';
include('C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\header.html');

if(isset($errors)&& !empty($errors))
{
    echo '<p id="err_msg">Oops! There was a problem:<br>';
    foreach($errors as $msg)

    {
        echo "-$msg<br>";

    }
            echo 'Please try again or <a href="register.php">Register</a></p>';
        }

?>

<h1>Login</h1>

<form action="login_action.php"method="POST">
<p>

Email Address: <input type="text" name="email">
</p><p>

Password: <input type="password" name="pass">
</p><p>

<input type ="submit" value = "Login">
</p>

</form>

<?php include ('C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\footer.html'); ?>
```

login_tools.php:

```
<?php

function load($page='C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\login.php')

{

$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$url=rtrim($url,'/\\');
$url.='/'.$page;    

header("Location:$url");
exit();

}

function validate($dbc, $email = '', $pwd = '')


{
    $errors = array();
    if(empty($email))
        {$errors[]=' Enter your email address.';}
    else

    {$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($email));}


    if(empty($pwd))
        {$errors[]=' Enter your password.';}
    else

        {$p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($pwd));}


    if(empty($errors))
        {
        $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE email = '$e' 
        AND pass =SHA1('$p')";

    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1)
        {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return array(true, $row);

        }
    else
        {$errors[] = ' Email address and password not found.';}

        }

return array(false, $errors);

}

?>


login_action.php:
```

The MySQL database is called 'site_db' with the table 'users'.

Comment: That's not how files are included. You should be using localhost path, not your disk's.

Comment: Have you tried just running the query RAW against the DB to ensure that its working as expected?

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie to MySQL and PHP as I am still learning. So I'm not too sure how to do this.

Comment: @JO'Donnell http://www.phptherightway.com

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I have now changed the code so that files are included with the shortened localhost path and not the disk's, however this has not changed anything.

Comment: Edit your question with the code you are now using and for future visitors. Your then-present audience may have already left the question and may not return to it.

Comment: You're also not using any POST arrays in conjunction with the form input elements, or have you left those out? you can ping anyone of us if you wish, I have now left it. Good luck

Comment: @JO'Donnell What you can do is to check your query and see if there are any rows matched with what you want. You might find that your query is not the one you expect.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with something weak like unsalted SHA1**.

Comment: I'd also strongly advise you to not put in literal paths like `C:\...` because that will make your code impossible to deploy on any computer other than your own.